# Boost.Serialization and Boost.Python two-way pickle

Tags: c++, python, boost, pickle, boost-serialization

I have a C++ library that uses Boost.Serialization. I'm creating Python bindings for this library using Boost.Python. It's fairly clear how to make a pickle suite for Boost.Python that uses Boost.Serialization (save to a string using Boost.Serialization, and return that string to Python).

What I want is the reverse: given a `boost::python::object`, I want to have a `serialize(...)` function that would call Python's `pickle.dumps()` function and serialize the resulting string. (Imagine an `std::vector<boost::python::object>`. As I serialize this vector, Boost.Serialization would call the auxiliary `serialize()` function.)  Is this possible? Better yet, is it possible to use `cPickle` and bypass giving the control to the Python interpreter?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am having the same problem now. I think defining a `namespace boost{namespace serialization{ template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive& a, boost::python::object& obj, const unsigned version){ /*...*/; } }}` should do the trick, but before I try... Thanks!

Comment: For me the bigger issue was how to use the pickle module itself. You can import it using boost::python::import. I eventually opted for a different solution to my specific problem that did not involve this question. The boost::serialization::serialize() function setup should work exactly as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to pickle/unpickle instance of boost::mersenne_twister

```
typedef boost::mt19937 rng_t;

struct mt_pickle_suite : bp::pickle_suite {

  static bp::object getstate (const rng_t& rng) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os);
    oa << rng;
    return bp::str (os.str());
  }

static void
  setstate(rng_t& rng, bp::object entries) {
    bp::str s = bp::extract<bp::str> (entries)();
    std::string st = bp::extract<std::string> (s)();
    std::istringstream is (st);

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia (is);
    ia >> rng;
  }
};
```

Comment: That's the wrong way; I understand how to pickle a C++ class through a stringstream. I want the other way around: use bp::object in Boost.Serialization (using Python's pickle).

Answer (score 0):

If your object is a native python object, then pickle.dumps() will do the trick.

In the other hand, if you have a std::vector, then you are mixing c++ and python. For that you will need to register the std::vector like:

```
using PyVec = std::vector<boost::python::object>;
boost::python::_class<PyVec, boost::noncopyable>
    ("PyVec", "My vector of PyObjects", boost::python::init<>() )
    .enable_pickling()
    .def_pickle( py_vec_pickle_suit() );
```

Then, of course you will need to define a pickle suit. But that is too cumbersome.

TL;DR: Use boost::python::list instead and call dump over it.